# How do I insert data from a query select string into a table in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

My question was deleted because of duplicate but this is not the case. My example uses an already made sql-string. The answer SO does not and where SO is referring to is way to complicated to implement in my solution. I try to edit my post and be more clearly about my issue. So I have a form which connects to an external database. My query qry_LIMS selects the relevant data.

```
    LIDNUMMER = "([LIDNUMMER] = " & LIDNUMMER_Integer & ")"
    MONSTERTYPE = "([MONSTERTYPE] = '" & Monstertype_String & "')"
    MONSTERNDATUM = "([MONSTERNDATUM] = '" & Datum_String & "')"

    
    strCriteria = LIDNUMMER & "And" & MONSTERTYPE & "And" & MONSTERNDATUM
    
    task = "Select * from qry_LIMS where (" & strCriteria & ")"

    Me.Form.RecordSource = task
```

What is the most easy way to insert all records from `task` into an other table named `tbl_LIMS`?

The named fields of my table `tbl_LIMS` are the same as `qry_LIMS`:

```
Lidnummer
Monstertype
Monsterndatum
```

I think the solution would rather easy but I do not seem to get it

```
INSERT INTO tbl_LIMS VALUES (task)
```

Comment: I've linked an additional question, it's just `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_LIMS " & task`. Note that the columns need to match exactly (including primary keys, and not creating invalid ones)

Comment: Thanks Erik A, I got it working with some minor adjustments: insertString = "INSERT INTO tbl_LIMS Select * FROM qry_LIMS where (" & strCriteria & ")"

CurrentDb.Execute (insertString)